# Hadoop jobs hanging waiting to be killed

Tags: java, hadoop, distributed-computing

I have multiple Hadoop jobs doing different processing. When exception occurs in some of these (custom business exception) it is propagated to the map() method, job is killed right away.

However some of the jobs are throwing exception in the setup() method in mapper class. When this happens job hangs for 40 minutes (my Hadoop timer has to be set to this), and with task re-run policy, I have to wait 4*40 = 160 minutes. In this particular case IllegalArgumentException is being thrown by one of business classes.

How could I handle this long "job hanging on cloud" period, but keeping my timer as is?

Comment: Well, this is exception caused by component I did not write, and this component is configured by providing URLs in Hadoop job configuration ;) It is runtime exception at the beginning of job init.

Comment: I've seen jobs failing in their setup phase (albeit not due to exceptions in the setup() method I think), I wonder why this is not happening. Maybe because it's a runtime exception?

Comment: Got it! Another thread was opened which performs scanning of some external resources. Because it was still opened in task JVM even after main thread got in exceptional state, job couldn't be killed and had to wait for timeout. Handling opened threads after exception occurs resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can kill a job on the command line with `hadoop job -kill <jobid>`

Comment: This would be rough solution from operational perspective. I don't want the users to kill job just because they have provided wrong (1 of 20) property in job configuration. This should be performed by Hadoop itself.